# SSH pubkey not working after change in user permissions

Tags: ssh, permissions, opensuse

Having set up a SuSE machine for a couple of co-developers, I found that SuSE does user permissions differently (all users being group "users", umask 022) than the RedHad / Gentoo way I am used to (all users having their own group, umask 002).

Thus, I went along and deleted all users, and re-created them each having their own group, and setting umask 002 globally.

However, after I did that, SSH pubkey authentication no longer works.

It *did* work before, and the `~/.ssh` directory *does* have mode 700, and the `~(/.ssh/authorized_keys` file *does* have mode 600, but SSH still insists on asking for a password, which it didn't do before the rework.

What did I miss?

Comment: Is the home directory also non-group-writable? If so, what appears in the logs from sshd when you try to log in?

Comment: Phrase it as an answer and you get the tick. Even if I had a look at the logs I wouldn't have thought the g+w on the home directory itself would make any difference, but it was indeed the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ssh daemon requires the whole chain of directory accesses from `/` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to be writable only by the user (and root), and in particular each of these must be non-group-writable. A common culprit is the home directory, which must be writable only by the user (mode 700 or 750 or 755) even if the user is alone in its group.